# Spring autowire of static configuration-object fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, static

as a Spring newbie I try to load external configuration into a Configuration-Object which I then try to autowire.

Following is my setup broken down to a bare minimum (less fields aso):
Package-structure:

```
app
  |--Application.java
app.configuration
  |--ConfigProperties.java
```

With my *configuration.properties* residing in:

```
src/main/resources/config
```

Application.java:

```
package app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import app.configuration.ConfigProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    //just to test if autowire works
    @Autowired
    public static ConfigProperties config;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println(config.getId());
    }
}
```

ConfigProperties.java:

```
package app.configuration;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/config/configuration.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
@Validated
public class ConfigProperties
{

    @NotBlank
    private String id;

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

This results in a NullPointerException for the line:

```
System.out.println(config.getId());
```

in the Apllication.java.

I read several posts on this topic but most imply that own instantiation prevents autowiring, which I am not doing, or that the scan can't find the class to autowire, but from what I read with my annotations and package structure that should not be the problem.

Where is/are my mistake(s)?

PS: it seems that properties are read correctly from the property file. If I test the validation, the expected error is thrown for Null-value if leave out the part where I try to autowire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Autowired
public static ConfigProperties config;
```

You cannot autowire `static` fields in Spring.

> //just to test if autowire works

You can write a new `Junit` test cases for that.

Something like:

```
@Autowired
public ConfigProperties config;
```

in your test class.

Comment: I didn't know that; thank you for the fast reply. assertNotNull-test seems to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the annotation `@Autowired` requires getters/setters to inject the correct implementation, I don't suggest you to wire a static content. However, there is a workaround for this issue:

```
public static ConfigProperties config;

@Autowired
public Application(ConfigProperties config) {
    Application.config= config;
}
```

Alternatively, take a look on the `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a static ConfigProperties .  Then use `@PostConstruct` to print the ID from your config object.

```
@Autowired
ConfigProperties config;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@PostConstruct 
void printId(){
    System.out.println("ID = " + config.getId());
}
```